# Classes in Lua, how does it work

Tags: lua

I'm new to Lua, and I'm trying to understand its OO part, for example :

```
lkw = {}
lkw.la= 0

function lkw:func(ge)
    self.la = self.la + ge
end

function lkw:new()
    local res = {}
    setmetatable(res, self)
    self.__index = self
    return res
end

mylkw = lkw:new()
```

in this example the "class" lkw can create object using new, but what do `self` and `index` mean ? 
should consider `self` as `this` in java/C++  and what is the index ?

Comment: `self` and function definition with `:` are explained in [Section 2.5.9](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.9) of the manual (and also in PiL, etc.). `__index` is explained in [Section 2.8 - Metatables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8).

Comment: @EtanReisner  so instead of using slef as first param I can use : for it , right?

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you define a function with `:` is "automagically" gets a self parameter (as the first parameter). When you call a function with `:` the item to the left of the `:` is "automagically" passed as the first argument.

Comment: sorry I read the Section 2.8 but still don't understand what does self mean or do

Comment: `self` is the first argument to the function. Using `:` in the definition hides that and using `:` in the call automatically passes it to the function. `lkw:new()` is the same as `lkw.new(lkw)`. And `function lkw:new()` is the same as `function lkw.new(self)`. That has nothing to do with metatables.

Comment: Lua has facilities that enable you to create your own class system. You should step back and learn them separately (from @EtanReisner's first comment) before trying to understand how someone else created their class system.

Comment: The book *Programming in Lua* discusses this some. You should probably read it. The first edition is online for free (and still largely relevant despite being written for lua 5.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This style of OOP is frequent in Lua. I do not like it because it is not explicit enough for me, but let me try to explain.

There are two confusing things: the use of the `:` sugar in function definitions and the use of the "class" as the metatable for its instances.

First, `function a:b(...)` is the same as `a.b = function(self, ...)`, so let us remove all sugar:

```
lkw = {}
lkw.la = 0

lkw.func = function(self, ge)
    self.la = self.la + ge
end

lkw.new = function(self)
    local res = {}
    setmetatable(res, self)
    self.__index = self
    return res
end

mylkw = lkw.new(lkw)
```

Now, this is "prototypal inheritance". `lkw` is the "prototype" for instances like `mylkw`. This is similar but slightly different from a "class".

When the `new` constructor is called, `lkw` is passed as the `self` argument.

The second and third lines of the constructor are weird. This is probably easier to understand:

```
lkw.new = function(self)
    local res = {}
    setmetatable(res, {__index = lkw})
    return res
end
```

i.e.: if we do not find something in the instance we go look for it inside the prototype.

This explains how `func` works. The first time it is called, the instance will not contain a `la` key so `lkw.la` will be used.

The reason the code is *not* written this way is that the weird construction allows "prototypal inheritance": you could call "new" on `mylkw` and get an "instance of the instance" (i.e. in prototypal inheritance an instance and a child class are the same thing).

I think this is a very confusing feature. For reference this is about how I would write code that does about the same thing, with no inheritance:

```
local methods = {
    func = function(self, ge)
        self.la = self.la + ge
    end
}

local lkw = {
    new = function()
        return setmetatable({la = 0}, {__index = methods})
    end
}

local mylkw = lkw.new()
```